# Expand a function in Maclaurin's series.

Tags: taylor-expansion

The function is given with:
$$\ln(5\cos^{3}(x))$$

Need to be expanded:
$$x^{4}$$

I have no idea what to do here and honestly, I don't really understand what a Maclaurin's series is. I know the definition but I don't understand the concept enough to be able to solve problems like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\cos x=1-\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{x^4}{4!}+o(x^4)$$
and thus
$$5\cos^3(x)=5\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+o(x^4)\right)^3=5-\frac{15x^2}{2!}+\frac{35}{8}x^4+o(x^4).$$

Moreover, if $x\longrightarrow  0$ you have that $5\cos^3(x)\longrightarrow  5$ and thus you have to develop $x\mapsto \ln(x)$ around $x=5$. That gives

$$\ln(x)=\ln(5)+\frac{1}{5}(x-5)-\frac{1}{25\cdot 2}(x-5)^2+o((x-5)^2).$$
Therefore

$$\ln(5\cos^3(x))=\ln(5)+\frac{1}{5}\left(-\frac{15x^2}{2!}+\frac{35}{8}x^4\right)-\frac{1}{50}\left(-\frac{15x^2}{2!}\right)^2+o(x^4)$$$$=\ln(5)-\frac{3}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{4}x^4+o(x^4)$$

Comment: wow, thanks, you helped me a lot :)

Comment: Why x = 5?
it is necessary that x = 0.

Comment: because if $x\to 0$ you have that $5\cos^3 x\to 5$.

Comment: i got it. thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

First note that 
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\ln(5\cos^3(x))=-\frac{3\sin(x)\cos^2(x)}{\cos^3x}=-3\tan(x).
$$
The Maclaurin series for $\tan x$ is
$$
x+\frac{1}{3}x^3+\frac{2}{15}x^5+\cdots
$$
So the derivative of your function has series
$$
-3x-x^3-\frac{2}{5}x^5-\cdots
$$
To get the series you want, integrate this series term by term:
$$
-\frac{3}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{4}x^4-\frac{2}{30}x^6-\cdots
$$

Comment: I now do not know what the answer is correct

Comment: @user.kos They are both correct.  We just used different methods.  If you simplify the other answer, you should get mine.

Comment: Okay, but is it possible to differentiate just like that?

Comment: Yes.  As long as you are in the radius of convergence, the derivative and antiderivative of a series is the derivative or antiderivative of the function it represents.

Comment: I got it. Remember the future this way, thank you :)